# LLSimpleCamera doesn't start recording

Tags: ios, camera, cocoapods, swift4

I'm using the pod LLSimpleCamera in my project. The problem is, that when I call to start video recording. It goes trough the code, but right below that (where is print isRecording) is always gives false.

Here is the button action

```
 @IBAction func shutterButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if videoMode == false {
        self.camera.capture({(camera, capturedImage, metadata, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                self.processImage(baseImage: capturedImage!)
            }
            else {
                print("An error has occured: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            }
        }, exactSeenImage: true)
    } else {
        if(camera.isRecording == false) {
            self.camera.startRecording(withOutputUrl: videoURL)
            print(self.camera.isRecording)
        } else {
            self.camera.stopRecording({ (camera, outputUrl, error) in
                print(self.camera.isRecording)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

My video URL is as followed

```
let videoURL: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "recording")
```

Comment: Have you provided correct `videoURL` path for recording video?

Comment: @BadhanGanesh I've added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be forming a valid `fileURL` with your code.

**Try changing this:**

```
let videoURL: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "recording")
```

**to this:**

```
// Here we get a path to your app's temp directory to save your recording to.
let outputPathString = "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())recording.mov"
let videoURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: outputPathString)
```